# Windows firewall which ports are opened for SQL Server named instance using dynamic port

Tags: sql-server, port, windows-firewall

In case of SQL Server named instances default configuration in to use TCP port which is dynamic and determined at the time the Database Engine starts.

The SQL Server Browser service listens for incoming connections to a named instance and provides the client the TCP port number that corresponds to that named instance.

I also understand a named instance can use a static port and in those case you can just open that port in your firewall.

What ports you open when using dynamic port for named instance and hosting multiple named instance in the same host?

Do you open the whole dynamic port range for TCP/UDP 49152–65535?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: That will only work when you one named instance in one host. What about multiple named instance in same host?

Comment: From the article: In the Program dialog box, select This program path. Click Browse, and **navigate to the instance of SQL Server that you want to access through the firewall**, and then click Open.

Comment: Different version of SQL server will have different path. So can I create separate rules for each named instance?

Comment: That's my take from the article. Each named instance of SQL Server will have a different path, so you could create a rule for each instance path.